# crontab schedule rule misunderstanding

Tags: crontab, scheduling

I've got some strange behavior of one rule working unexpected.

```
*/40 * * * * myshellcommand here
```

I though it would run each 40 minutes, e.g.

```
00.00
00.40
01.20
02.00
etc
```

but instead it runs

```
00.00
00.40
01.00
01.40
02.00
etc.
```

Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.  It is working as intended.  * resets itself at the beginning of every hour/day/month.  Put another way, * is a stand-in for the maximum range of the value in question.  So * in the minutes column stands in for 0-59, and */40 means "starting at 0, run every 40 minutes up to 59". See 'Special characters' on the [cron Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for more info.

What you probably need to do is run the job every 20 minutes, and have the program decide whether or not it should run.  Or, do it with two lines

```
0,40 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * myshellcommand
20   1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23 * * * myshellcommand
```

Note that this can be written in a slightly more compact form:

```
0,40 */2    * * * myshellcommand
20   1-23/2 * * * myshellcommand
```

In this case, */2 indicates every second hour starting from 0 (since * is equivalent to 0-23), and 1-23/2 indicates every second hour starting from hour 1.

Comment: Thanks. probably you're right. if no other opinion appears I'll accept your answer as correct